# Jaccard distance to a vector of a ‘profile’ instead of ML model?

Tags: cosine-distance, jaccard-coefficient

I’ve been trying to find the best method to a problem and I can’t find any good solutions, probably because I don’t know how to ask the questions right.

I have have a population of people that I am trying to rank their likelihood of an event, ex. purchasing Widgets. I have some purchased data where I KNOW certain individuals that are Widget People (WP) but the rest of the population I have no idea if they are WP or not. So I didn’t want to train a ML model with the WP against the rest of the population since the rest will have some WP in it and therefore muddy the data.

I had a thought to gather data points of the WP and get a ‘profile’ vector based on the averages of those data points. Then take the jaccard distance (or Cosine Similarity etc.) of the vectors for each other person so the get a score and can be ranked based on how closely they resemble the profile.

Would this be a reasonable method for my goal? Is there some obvious methods that exist that would be better?